# How do I use C# and ADO.NET to query an Oracle table with a spatial column of type SDO_GEOMETRY?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, 64-bit, spatial

My development machine is running Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit version. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate. I am connecting to an Oracle 11g Enterprise server version 11.1.0.7.0. I had a difficult time locating Oracle client software that is made for 64-bit Windows systems and eventually landed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle11g/111060_win64soft.html) to download what I assume is the proper client connectivity software. I added a reference to "Oracle.DataAccess" which is version 2.111.6.0 (Runtime Version is v2.0.50727). I am targeting .NET CLR version 4.0 since all properties of my VS Solution are defaults and this is 2010 RC. I was then able to write a console application in C# that established connectivity, executed a SELECT statement, and properly returned data when the table in question does NOT contain a spatial column. My problem is that this no longer works when the table I query has a column of type SDO_GEOMETRY in it.

Below is the simple console application I am trying to run that reproduces the problem. When the code gets to the line with the "ExecuteReader" command, an exception is raised and the message is "Unsupported column datatype".

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace ConsoleTestOracle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oradb = string.Format("Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};",
                "hostname/servicename", "login", "password");

            try
            {
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from SDO_8307_2D_POINTS";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that this code works when used against a table that does not contain a spatial column of type SDO_GEOMETRY makes me think I have my windows 7 machine properly configured so I am surprised that I get this exception when the table contains different kinds of columns. I don't know if there is some configuration on my machine or the Oracle machine that needs to be done, or if the Oracle client software I have installed is wrong, or old and needs to be updated.

Here is the SQL I used to create the table, populate it with some rows containing points in the spatial column, etc. if you want to try to reproduce this exactly.

SQL Create Commands:

```
create table SDO_8307_2D_Points (ObjectID number(38) not null unique, TestID number, shape SDO_GEOMETRY);
Insert into SDO_8307_2D_Points values (1, 1, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10.0, 10.0)));
Insert into SDO_8307_2D_Points values (2, 2, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10.0, 20.0)));
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values ('SDO_8307_2D_Points', 'SHAPE', SDO_DIM_ARRAY(SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Lat', -180, 180, 0.05), SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Long', -90, 90, 0.05)), 8307);
create index SDO_8307_2D_Point_indx on SDO_8307_2D_Points(shape) indextype is mdsys.spatial_index PARAMETERS ('sdo_indx_dims=2' );
```

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: oracle SDO objects are essentially arrays within arrays.  The Oracle JDBC libraries deal with this just fine as a JGeometry type.  If you don't have that data type, then simply query as sdo_util.to_wktgeometry but you will have to deal with them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a post with a sample app using C# and ODP.net to access spatial types.

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/27794/296419/0/#msg_296419

There is also a sample here about using XML to select the spatial types:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=241076